# "No default constructor exists for class" why is it needed?

Tags: c++, class, struct, constructor, default-constructor

```
struct point {
    int x; int y;
    point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    int sum = x + y;
};
class circle {
public:
    point p;
    double r;
    circle(point a, double b) {
        p = a;
        r = b;
    }
    //circle(point a, double b) : p(a), r(b) {}; //no error
};
```

An error message saying "No default constructor exists for class point" appeared in circle constructor. Why default constructor for point is needed?

Comment: Please add a language tag. Is this C++?

Comment: Code uses c++ syntax (most likely).